# realizar consulta a la bd desde un select con los meses del año

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola a todo estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a la base de datos desde un select, quiero que al seleccionar el mes ejecute la consulta de ese mes y año ejemplo

```
<select name="mes">
   <option value="1">Enero</option>
   <option value="2">Febrero</option>
   <option value="3">Marzo</option>
   <option value="4">Abril</option>
   <option value="5">Mayo</option>
   <option value="6">Junio</option>
   <option value="7">Julio</option>
   <option value="8">Agosto</option>
   <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
   <option value="10">Octubre</option>
   <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
   <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
</select>
```

recibo los datos

```
$inicio="";
$fin="";
if($_POST["mes"] == 1){ 
$inicio="2019-01-01";
$fin="2019-01-31";
}else if($_POST["mes"] == 2){ 
$inicio="2019-02-01";
$fin="2019-02-28";
}
```

y asi con cada mes para realizar la consulta a la base de datos de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT * FROM tblprestamo WHERE prestamoEstado=3 AND BETWEEN $inicio AND $fin
```

pero que pasa si el año cambia me tocaria cambiar los datos en la aplicacion, me gustaria que fuera dinamico o si pudiera concatenar ejemplo

```
$inicio = "date('Y')-01-01"; //para que el año fuera dinamico
```

o como deberia de realizar esta consulta solo seleccionando el mes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí lo que quieres hacer es, tienes un Select con los años, y un select con los meses, lo que tu quieres es que en la consulta te traiga todos los registros de ese mes y año, lo que yo haría seria lo siguiente

```
Select * from tblprestamo where Year(fechacontralaquevalidas)=año and Month(fechacontralaquevalidas)=mes
```

es decir asumiendo que el campo es FechaRegistro y el mes(1-12) 10 y año que te interesa es 2019 quedaría así.

```
Select * from tlbprestamo where year(FechaRegistro)=8 and year(FechaRegistro)=YEAR(CURDATE())
```

En el año en lugar de buscar una variable, buscamos el año de la fecha actual y listo.

De esta forma te traerá todo el mes sin tener que calcular cuando inicia o acaba el mes corriente.

Comment: solo tengo un select con los meses y dependiendo el mes que seleccione me traiga los registros de ese mes ejemplo si selecciono noviembre me traiga todos los registros del mes de noviembre del año en que estoy, y si selecciono noviembre el otro año(2020) me traiga los registros del año actual y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta, pero solo es necesario modificar la parte del año para que en lugar de tomar el año que envies, tome el año actual

Answer (score 1):

En MariaDB y MySQL puedes utilizar las funciones `YEAR` con `CURDATE` o `NOW`:

```
 $inicio = "YEAR(NOW())-01-01"
```

Comment: le sentencia estaria quedando asi 'SELECT * FROM tblprestamo WHERE prestamoEstado=3 AND fechaPago BETWEEN "YEAR(NOW())-09-01" AND "YEAR(NOW())-09-30"' pero me sale error Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'YEAR(NOW())-09-01'

Comment: YEAR(NOW()) es una función asi que tendrias que retirarlos de los parentesis. Una solución seria separar el año del `BETWEEN`ya que siempre es el mismo. (Eg. `'SELECT * FROM tblprestamo WHERE prestamoEstado=3 AND YEAR(fechaPago) = YEAR(NOW()) AND fechaPago BETWEEN to_date("09-01", "DD-MON")  AND to_date("09-30", "DD-MON")'`)

Comment: gracias por responder pero esta consulta me trae error tambien Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: '09-01'

Comment: Disculpa. Se me cruzaron los pinceles con SQL Server. En MYSQL sería.
`'SELECT * FROM tblprestamo WHERE prestamoEstado=3 AND YEAR(fechaPago) = YEAR(NOW()) AND fechaPago BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("09-10", "%d-%m") AND STR_TO_DATE("09-30", "%d-%m");'`

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo tienes, puedes usar `date("Y");` de `PHP`, así:

```
$inicio = "";
$fin = "";
$year = date("Y");//asigna el valor del año actual a la variable $year 
                  //para concatenarla luego en $inicio y $fin
if($_POST["mes"] == 1){ 
  $inicio = $year."-01-01";
  $fin = $year."-01-31";
}else if($_POST["mes"] == 2){ 
  $inicio = $year."-02-01";
  $fin = $year."-02-28";
}
```

Otra opción que tienes es utilizar la función `cal_days_in_month()` de `PHP` que calcula el número de días del mes que le envíes por `POST`, así por ejemplo:

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = $_POST["mes"];
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

$inicio = $year."-".$month."-01";
$fin = $year."-".$month."-".$days;
```

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias a Todos por responder en la respuesta que escribio @thepanch esta la respuesta solo que en vez de year hay que colocar `MONTH(FechaFin)`
la sentencia quedaria asi

```
SELECT * FROM tblprestamo WHERE prestamoEstado=3 AND MONTH(prestamoFechaFin)= '$mes' AND YEAR(prestamoFechaFin) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

con esto me ahorra codigo ya que no tengo que estar escribiendo el principio y el fin de cada mes

Comment: Muchas gracias, no olvides marcar como respuesta la correcta de esa forma nos ayudas a todos